# Core ML: UIImage from RGBA byte array not fully shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In combination with `Core ML`, I am trying to show a `RGBA byte array` in an `UIImage` using the following code:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bytes, width, height, 8, 4 * width, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
CFRelease(colorSpace);

CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
CGContextRelease(context);

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
CGImageRelease(cgImage);

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[self predictionView] setImage:image];
});
```

I create the image data like this:

```
 uint32_t offset = h * width * 4 + w * 4;
 struct Color rgba = colors[highestClass];
 bytes[offset + 0] = (rgba.r);
 bytes[offset + 1] = (rgba.g);
 bytes[offset + 2] = (rgba.b);
 bytes[offset + 3] = (255 / 2); // semi transparent
```

The image size is `500px` by `500px`. However the full image is not shown, it looks like the image is shown `50%` zoomed in.

I started searching for this issue, and found others having the same issue as well. That's why I decided to edit my `StoryBoard` and set different values for the `Content Mode`, currently I use `Aspect Fit`. However, the result remains the same.

I also tried to draw a horizontal line in the center of the image to show how much the image is zoomed in. It confirms that the image is zoomed in `50%`.

I wrote the same code in `swift`, which is working fine. See the code and result on `swift` here:

```
let offset = h * width * 4 + w * 4
let rgba = colors[highestClass]
bytes[offset + 0] = (rgba.r)
bytes[offset + 1] = (rgba.g)
bytes[offset + 2] = (rgba.b)
bytes[offset + 3] = (255/2) // semi transparent

let image = UIImage.fromByteArray(bytes, width: width, height: height,
               scale: 0, orientation: .up,
               bytesPerRow: width * 4,
               colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
               alphaInfo: .premultipliedLast)
```

https://github.com/hollance/CoreMLHelpers/blob/master/CoreMLHelpers/UIImage%2BCVPixelBuffer.swift

[image]

And below the wrong result in `objective-c`. You can see that it's very pixelated compared to the `swift` one. The phone is an iPhone 6s.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

[image: iPhone 6s screenshot]

[image: XCode screenshot]

Comment: did you try to change your scale in `UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage scale:0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];` to `[image scale]`

Comment: A screen shot would be helpful. It might be an issue with the scale.

Comment: Check updated question

Comment: How did you get `bytes`? Can you share?

Comment: @sahara108 I create them manually, please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my problem. It turned out that it had nothing to do with the image stuff itself. There was a bug that the values (`width` and `height`) of `500`does not fit in `uint8_t`. That's why the image was shown smaller. Very stupid. Changing it to the right values worked.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to show a `RGB` byte array

Then `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` is incorrect. Try to switch to `kCGImageAlphaNone`.

Comment: My fault, it's ARGB!

Comment: If ARGB then alpha last is also incorrect. You need to use `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst` or `kCGImageAlphaFirst`

Comment: Yes, thanks. However that will not solve the scaling issue.